# Cutting Bael tree branches, Sin?

Tags: shiva

I have a Bael tree in my home ,every year the branches encroaching on the outside public road , we have no option but to cut the branches, does doing so is direct invitation to some misfortune..

Comment: Simply cutting the branches may not be a sin because that's required for grooming and that does not kill the plant either but if you uproot the tree then that can be a sin.